# How to make a click inside a tooltip not close it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The tooltip is shown on the `mouseover` event and closed on `click`.

```js
"use strict";

var toolTipHover = function toolTipHover(ev) {
  var tt = document.getElementById("tooltip");

  if (ev.type == "mouseover") {
    if (ev.target.tagName == "A") {
      var href = ev.target.getAttribute("href");

      if (href.length > 1 && href.slice(0, 2) == "#n") {
        var a = document.querySelector("[id=" + href.substr(1) + "]");

        if (a) {
          tt.style.opacity = "1";
          tt.style.transition = "0.35s";
          tt.style.zIndex = "100";
          tt.innerHTML = "<span style='color:blue;'>" + a.textContent + ".</span> " + a.nextSibling.textContent;  
          tt.style.left = Math.min(ev.pageX, window.pageXOffset + window.innerWidth - tt.offsetWidth - 23) + "px";
          tt.style.top = (ev.pageY + 15 > window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight - tt.offsetHeight - 23 ? ev.pageY - tt.offsetHeight : ev.pageY + 15) + "px";
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    tt.style.opacity = "0";
    tt.style.zIndex = "-1";
  }
};

["mouseover", "click"].map(function (ev) {
  return document.body.addEventListener(ev, toolTipHover);
});

document.write('<div id="tooltip"></div>');
```

```css
#tooltip {
  position: absolute; 
  z-index: 100;
  max-width: 350px; 
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.35s ease-out;
  font: normal 13px/1.3 "Segoe UI", arial, sans-serif; 
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #777; 
  background-color: #ffffd5;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
}
.notes {font: 13px arial; padding: 0 3px; vertical-align: text-top;}
pre    {white-space: pre-line; font: 14px times;}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum<a href="#n01" id="r01" class="notes">[1]</a> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum<a href="#n02" id="r02" class="notes">[2]</a> exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur...
<hr>
<pre>
<b>notes:</b>
<a href="#r01" id="n01">1</a> Consectetur adipiscing elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh. Ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa...
<a href="#r02" id="n02">2</a> Enim praesent elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla est. Nisl condimentum id venenatis a...
</pre>
```

**How to make a click inside a tooltip not close it?**

Comment: You register the tooltip with `["mouseover", "click"]`. You show it if the event type is mouseover (`if (ev.type == "mouseover")`). So naturally it will close if you click. Have you tried removing click from the events or adding it to the `if`? Shouldn't you handle `mouseout` to hide the tooltip?

Comment: Yes. But when there is a lot of text in the tooltip, scrolling appears and all the text cannot be read. Therefore, it is better to close on click.

Answer (score 1):

For your click event, you can check whether the clicked element or one of it's ancestors is the tooltip

```js
"use strict";

var toolTipHover = function toolTipHover(ev) {
  var tt = document.getElementById("tooltip");

  if (ev.type == "mouseover") {
    if (ev.target.tagName == "A") {
      var href = ev.target.getAttribute("href");

      if (href.length > 1 && href.slice(0, 2) == "#n") {
        var a = document.querySelector("[id=" + href.substr(1) + "]");

        if (a) {
          tt.style.opacity = "1";
          tt.style.transition = "0.35s";
          tt.style.zIndex = "100";
          tt.innerHTML = "<span style='color:blue;'>" + a.textContent + ".</span> " + a.nextSibling.textContent;  
          tt.style.left = Math.min(ev.pageX, window.pageXOffset + window.innerWidth - tt.offsetWidth - 23) + "px";
          tt.style.top = (ev.pageY + 15 > window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight - tt.offsetHeight - 23 ? ev.pageY - tt.offsetHeight : ev.pageY + 15) + "px";
        }
      }
    }
  } else if (ev.target.id !== 'tooltip' && !ev.target.closest('#tooltip')) { // add this check
    tt.style.opacity = "0";
    tt.style.zIndex = "-1";
  }
};

["mouseover", "click"].map(function (ev) {
  return document.body.addEventListener(ev, toolTipHover);
});

document.write('<div id="tooltip"></div>');
```

```css
#tooltip {
  position: absolute; 
  z-index: 100;
  max-width: 350px; 
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.35s ease-out;
  font: normal 13px/1.3 "Segoe UI", arial, sans-serif; 
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #777; 
  background-color: #ffffd5;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
}
.notes {font: 13px arial; padding: 0 3px; vertical-align: text-top;}
pre    {white-space: pre-line; font: 14px times;}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum<a href="#n01" id="r01" class="notes">[1]</a> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum<a href="#n02" id="r02" class="notes">[2]</a> exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur...
<hr>
<pre>
<b>notes:</b>
<a href="#r01" id="n01">1</a> Consectetur adipiscing elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh. Ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa...
<a href="#r02" id="n02">2</a> Enim praesent elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla est. Nisl condimentum id venenatis a...
</pre>
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. But in IE 11.0, the tooltip no longer closes when clicking outside its area.

Comment: you are going to need a polyfill for `closest` if you are still supporting ie - do you need to support it as [microsoft stopped supporting it in June](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2022/06/15/internet-explorer-11-has-retired-and-is-officially-out-of-support-what-you-need-to-know/)

Comment: And if instead of a method `closest` there is another check that is compatible with IE?

Comment: that's why I said use a polyfill - have a google, there are plenty out there

Comment: If you remove this part of the code `&& !ev.target.closest('#tooltip')`, then everything works in IE. It won't be critical?

Comment: but click on the span with the blue text in your tooltip - it will close it if you don't have closest

Comment: Then `<span id='ttnumber'..`. and `..ev.target.id !== 'tooltip' && ev.target.id !== 'ttnumber'..`. Works.